# Java streams: merge/map collections

Tags: java, java-stream

I've this class:

```
private class Item {
  private String transactionId;
  private String user;
  private LocalDate expiration;
  private String confidential;
  private String locked;
}
```

By other hand, I've five collections:

```
List<String> transactions;
List<String> users;
List<LocalDate> expirations;
List<String> confidential;
List<String> lockeds;
```

So I need to map each n of each collection to a new `Item` object.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Stream over the indices (assuming all 5 lists have the same number of elements):

```
List<Item> items = IntStream.range(0,transactions.size())
                            .mapToObj(i -> new Item(transactions.get(i),
                                                    users.get(i),
                                                    expirations.get(i),
                                                    confidential.get(i),
                                                    lockeds.get(i)))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: It's telling me that `IntStream.map` has to return an integer... `cannot convert from Item to int`

Comment: @Jordi oops. you're right. I'll fix it. It should be `mapToObj`

Comment: Only one more question... Could I create anonimous type?

Comment: @Jordi what do you mean? What would that anonymous type implement/extend?

Comment: I mean, if it's possible to create a "dynamic" map object without declaring any class, or declaring it on the fly inside `mapToObj`